# Optimizing google app script for implementing auto-increment columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

There are two ways that i am able to add an auto increment column. By auto-increment, i mean that if column B has a value, column A will be incremented by a numeric value that increments based on the previous rows value.

The first way of doing this is simple, which is to paste a formula like the one below in my first column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),,IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,0)+1)
```

The second way i have done this is via a GA script.  What i found however is performance using a GA script is much slower and error prone.  For example if i pasted values quickly in the cells b1 to b10 in that order, it will at times reset the count and start at 1 again for some rows.  This is because the values for the previous rows have not yet been calculated.  I assume that this is because the GA scripts are probably run asynchronously and in parallel. My question is..is there a way to make sure each time a change happens, the execution of this script is queued and executed in order?
OR, is there a way i should write this script to optimize it?

```
function auto_increment_col() {
  ID_COL = 1;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //only increment column 1 for sheets in this list
  var auto_inc_sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("auto_inc_sheets").getValues();
  auto_inc_sheets = auto_inc_sheets.map(function(row) {return row[0];});
  var is_auto_inc_sheet = auto_inc_sheets.indexOf(spreadsheet.getSheetName()) != -1;
  if (!is_auto_inc_sheet) return;

  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var last_row        = worksheet.getLastRow();
  var last_inc_val = worksheet.getRange(last_row, ID_COL).getValue();

  //if auto_inc column is blank and the column next to auto_inc column (col B) is not blank, then assume its a new row and increment col A
  var is_new_row = last_inc_val == "" && worksheet.getRange(last_row, ID_COL+1).getValue() != "";
  Logger.log("new_row:" + is_new_row + ", last_inc_val:" + last_inc_val );
  if (is_new_row) {
    var prev_inc_val = worksheet.getRange(last_row-1, ID_COL).getValue();
    worksheet.getRange(last_row, ID_COL).setValue(prev_inc_val+1);
  }
}
```

Comment: With respect, but honesty, I don't understand what you are trying to do. You don't say how the script is triggered, you don't give the range for  "auto_inc_sheets", you don't say how long the sheet normally takes to recalculate, etc. You would be familiar with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Would you please  edit your question to provide a Minimal Reproducible example? And please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding private or confidential information),including an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: The reason your code is slow is that you are using many calls to external services (any SpreadsheetApp method counts as such, see Apps Script Best Practices: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) If you want to wait between two calls, you can use SpreadsheetApp.flush(); https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush

Answer (score 1):

There is my vision of auto increment https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/spreadsheet_autoincrement

The main function of this is

```
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} sheet
 */
function autoincrement_(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  if (data.length < 2) return;
  var indexCol = data[0].indexOf('autoincrement');
  if (indexCol < 0) return;
  var increment = data.map(function(row) {
    return row[indexCol];
  });
  var lastIncrement = Math.max.apply(
    null,
    increment.filter(function(e) {
      return isNumeric(e);
    })
  );

  lastIncrement = isNumeric(lastIncrement) ? lastIncrement : 0;
  var newIncrement = data
    .map(function(row) {
      if (row[indexCol] !== '') return [row[indexCol]];
      if (row.join('').length > 0) return [++lastIncrement];
      return [''];
    })
    .slice(1);
  sheet.getRange(2, indexCol + 1, newIncrement.length).setValues(newIncrement);
}
```

But you have to open the snippet for details because this doesn't work without locks.